# Google Maps API key returning null reference to the routes

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am fetching driving routes from Google maps using google maps api key. when i am using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Madhapur&destination=secunderabad i am getting the correct results and able to draw the routes but when i am using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Madhapur&destination=secunderabad&key=My_API_Key i am getting null point refernece for PolylineOoptions reference.

Comment: using this am getting response with route data https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Madhapur&destination=secunderabad. Check that you have enabled direction API for the given API_key

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) if you haven't already... But yes, it should be because of you Key,did you activate your API and get that Key?

Comment: I don't know the complexity you need, but I don't use the directly the url. I use the Directions Service, Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)